# Is there a Specific Axelar Executor Address I can Whitelist?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, axelar

I see the address `0xD36aac0c9676e984D72823Fb662ce94D3Ab5E551` refers to the address Axelar executor service. It shows up when sending a GMP from my MoonbaseAlpha to my Binance Test net smart contract https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x050734dd68fc627ffc4a7e6017275f46b241238d2f5e774b226b89ba9fbea9a2.

Is this the same address for all chains?

I am trying to ensure that if I whitelist my smart contract to only accept messages from this address`0xD36aac0c9676e984D72823Fb662ce94D3Ab5E551` that:

1. This address is the same for all my satellite smart contracts across all chains
2. This Relayer address will not change

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current executor uses the same address across chains, but it is not recommended to rely on this assumption as it may change in the future.

However, the correct architecture is to verify the source chain and address in your _execute method, which is ensured to be true by the verification performed in the execute method by the gateway. You can refer to the code snippet provided in the link below for the implementation:

https://github.com/axelarnetwork/axelar-gmp-sdk-solidity/blob/main/contracts/executable/AxelarExecutable.sol#L25-L28